# For government / industry research posters, should I include my university's logo?

Tags: university, acknowledgement, poster

For an undergraduate putting together a research poster describing research worked on at a government lab, is it appropriate to include the undergraduate's home institution in the Acknowledgements section?

Assume, in this case, the undergraduate institution has no involvement in the research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would think about it:

- You were at the government lab when you did the research, so its logo definitely needs to be there
- You are preparing the logo and presenting the poster while at the university, so it's reasonable for its logo to be there as well.

With such things, it's usually better to err on the side of inclusiveness: people or organizations are much more likely to feel it's problematic to *not* be included than to feel it's problematic to be included, as long as there is *some* reasonable connection.

Answer (score 1):

If the work at the lab was in any way related to your course, such as part of a placement or project you get credit for, then I would include the university's logo.

However, if the university was in no way involved, for example if this was a summer project that you found independently, then the university's logo probably doesn't need to be on the poster.

In any case if you are unsure then the best idea is probably to talk to someone who was involved in the project and possibly also someone from your university (your personal tutor or similar). They will be best placed to advise you for your particular situation.